# Implementing CustomErrors within Web API project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributes

I'm trying to implement custom error handling within a Web API project using my web.config file.  My issue is that the redirect is not happening.  I have the following set up in my web config:

```html
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Page/Error?errorId=59">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Page/Error?errorId=59"/>
</customErrors>
```

This is where it may be tricky:
I'm using a custom attribute that I'm placing in my controller, and the attribute returns a 403 status code if the request is not coming from a listed referrer.

Here's the attribute Code:

```
public class Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // pre-processing
        HttpRequestMessage request = actionContext.Request;
       string ipAddress = ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (!IsIpAddressAllowed(ipAddress.Trim()))
        {
           actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
```

Then I add the attribute to my controller like so:

```
[Action1DebugActionWebApiFilter]
[HttpGet]
[Route("MyRedirect")]
public IHttpActionResult MyRedirect([FromUri]UserModel myUser)
```

I know the 403 is getting produced because I can see it in my Firefox network tab.  But the redirect isn't happening (verified in Fiddler).  I just get a blank screen on the controller redirect with all the Get parameters just sitting there.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is because the `<customErrors>` section does not control asp web api.

Comment: Thanks Peco... actually the top level default of customErrors does work.  It's the sub-errors that don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `<customErrors>` section does not apply to asp web api.